# How to create Java objects from a nested JSON file using gson?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I am trying to use gson to help me create Java objects from a JSON. Some sample example will be very helpful.

Edit 1: 
Sample JSON:

```
{
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "updatedate": "16/08/2015",
  "comment": "Sample JSON.",
  "categories": [
    {
      "name": "Service",
      "id": 13,
      "taxesIDs": [],
      "taxTypeID": 3
    }
  ],
  "countries": [
    {
      "name": "Canada",
      "id": 4
    }
  ],
  "states": [
    {
      "name": "Yukon",
      "id": 151,
      "country": "Canada",
      "price": [
        {
          "name": "Sales",
          "id": 1,
          "taxes": [
            {
              "name": "General",
              "id": 1,
              "percent": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "Electronics",
              "id": 19,
              "percent": 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Income",
          "id": 2,
          "taxes": [
            {},
            {}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Service",
          "id": 3,
          "taxes": [
            {},
            {}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to Parse the above JSON and Create Java Classes with same hierarchy. 
Thanks.

Comment: did you google anything?

Comment: I googled but didn't find any useful clear example.

Comment: please visit https://tauqirblog.wordpress.com/json-parsing-using-gson-with-url/

Comment: @Tauqir this is straight forward. What about nested JSONs have you worked on that? Thanks.

Comment: Please paste any complex json string as per your requirement. I might suggest something.

Answer (score 3):

Use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) link to create your Java pojo class from json.

Than use the class like this ,

```
YourObject obj = gson.fromJson(yourjsonstring, YourObject.class);
```

For more information follow [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) link.

Comment: Thanks but throws error my JSON is too big for this; "There's a problem: Your input was larger than 51200 characters, try making this a bit smaller"

Answer (score 1):

We just need to architect our Java Classes in the same manner as our JSON. Specifically in my case:

```
Class Source {
String version, comment, updatedate;
Category[] categories;
Country[] countries;
State[] states;
}

Class Category {
String name;
...
}
```

Similarly for State, Price, Tax classes.

Once the Data Structure is ready one can use GSON as mentioned by @serhatSS.

```
String jsonString = new String(data);    // You have data in response
Gson gson = new Gson();
Source source = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Source.class);
```

Now Source class will have all the data in its members and can be accessed by:

```
Source.countries  // of type Country
Source.comment    // String
```

Thanks!